# dynamic filtering function that can accept key as matcher

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did a filter to filter grade.

https://jsbin.com/jivosegagi/edit?html,js,console

```
var arr = [{
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "A"
}, {
    "name": "Alice",
    "grade": "B"
}, {
    "name": "Terrence",
    "grade": "C"
}, {
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "A"
}, {
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "D"
}, {
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "D"
}];

const selectedGrade = "C";

let x = arr.filter(obj => obj.grade === selectedGrade)

console.log(x);
```

It worked of course it's easy. But above is just a miniature set of my bigger challenge. I call API to get data, I have no control over the naming of the api data. What if the display text for A,B,C,D is different than the data given by the API?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? still somewhat unclear...

Comment: In this case you have hardcoded the selectedGrade to be `C` . How are you  getting the selected grade in genral

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri when the user chose an option in `select`

Answer (score 0):

In your case what you need to do is to find out all the distince grades that are available from your API response and then populate these in the select field by mapping over this array of distinct grades.

After this you can filter out your response as you are doing

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "A"
}, {
    "name": "Alice",
    "grade": "B"
}, {
    "name": "Terrence",
    "grade": "C"
}, {
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "A"
}, {
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "D"
}, {
    "name": "james",
    "grade": "D"
}];

var unique = {};
var distinct = [];
for( var i in arr){
 if( typeof(unique[arr[i].grade]) == "undefined"){
  distinct.push(arr[i].grade);
 }
 unique[arr[i].grade] = 0;
}

console.log(distinct)
```

Comment: Did you try this out?